# Can you set specific weights to be zero in tensorflow keras layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is some example; For example, let's say I want that kernel[i]=0 if i>3 and i<d/2; How would I implement it into the kernel contraints?

```
d=30
x_in=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=d)
x_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(d, kernel_contraint= "kernel[i]=0 if i>3 and i<d/2")(x_in)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x_in, outputs=x_out)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='MeanAbsoluteError')

X=tf.random.uniform([100,d])
Y=tf.random.uniform([100,d])


model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

Update: Since d can be derived from the shape of the weight matrix, I do not need any input; Observe that I can combine it with other constraints, e.g. that the values are non-negative

```
class custom_con(tf.keras.constraints.Constraint):

    def __call__(self, W):
        W[0,0].assign(0)
        return W * tf.cast(tf.greater_equal(W, 0.), backend.floatx())
```

This is an example, where I set the weight matrix at the position [0,0] equal to zero and demand all values to be greater than 0; It is obvious how to do the upper task (get d via W.shape, then use e.g. a for loop)

Comment: You probably need to [implement a custom constraint](https://keras.io/api/layers/constraints/#creating-custom-weight-constraints)

Comment: Isn't the simple way to do this to multiply `x_in` by a tensor built from a list comprehension such as `[int(x < 3) for x in range(x_in.shape)]`? That's just a sketch, but should do the trick...

Comment: I try to custom build a constraint; @philosofool How would that work? if you have d inputs and d outputs, your weight matrix is d x d ; So if you set single values x_i to zero, this will cause problems

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I solved the question myself and updated it accordingly @AloneTogether I can delete it if this is preferred but I thought it might be interesting for people

Comment: No problem. Was just wondering.